# py2exe difficulties

Tags: python, exe, converters

With some useful answers of my previous question (See below), I decided to give py2exe another try.

I tried the tutorial from py2exe.org (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial), but got an error at step 3. I did 1 and 2 exactly as told, and put both files (hello.py and setup.py) in my main folder where I installed python in: D:\Programs\Python.

When running the 'code' form step 3 I got the following error, totally on the bottom of the output:
"ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32-application.*"
I've got a screenshot of the entire output, but I don't know where to upload it.

Extra information:
I have 64bit Windows 7 (profesional) and Python 2.7.3 (first I had 3.3.0, but downgraded because of some reasons). It is not a big problem for me to change to another version. I downloaded py2exe 0.6.9.

Note: I couldn't choose between py2exe for 32- or 64bit. I guess then a error should show up earlier, but it might be handy to know.

*I literally translated the last part from Dutch, so it can be slightly different then English pc's.

Previous question:

What is the easiest .py to .exe converter?
I've tried a few converters, of which cx_Freeze and py2exe. Using cx_Freeze was too complicated (I couldn't find a good tutorial) and py2exe gave some errors. Before I'm going to try to understand one of these two or try another one, I want some input which converter you think is the best, and I need a good tutorial.
I have barely experience with cmd, and am quite a newbie if it comes to programming/python, so I am looking for the easiest-to-use converter.
If you say I really need some cmd experience, please direct me to a cmd tutorial/course.

Comment: you mean you want a compiler? not all python scripts can be compiled, without generating a HUGE .exe as you have to embed the entire python interpreter within the exe

Answer (score 3):

you can use [GUI2exe](https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) that's the easiest way im my opinion !

You wont learn much about the converter's but it gets the job done without any problems.

ps. GUI2exe isnt a converter , its a gui to use the converters!

Comment: Thanks, with GUI2Exe I can understand wat I'm doing! Still, py2exe is giving me errors. I will try it with cx_Freeze...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of erros does py2exe give you?  That is what I use and it works like a charm for me.

Comment: I tried the tutorial from the py2exe.org (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and I only got to step 3, when I type python setup.py py2exe it gives a big list, and on the end is the following error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing (I'm Dutch,  a rough translation of that last part: %1 is not a valid Win32-aplication)
I put the hello.py and the setup.py file in my python installation folder (D:\Programs\Python)

Answer (score 0):

I've used `py2exe` previously. I assume you've looked at the [tutorial](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) on the py2exe project page?

There is also a good one available on the [Python Library](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/) page.

I used `py2exe` for complicated Python/Qt/PyQt applications. The biggest thing you'll need to know about that is that the `MSVCP90.dll` file is needed. You can get that from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en). You'll then need to copy it and the other files mentioned in it's license to the Python DLLs directory. Detailed instructions are available on the py2exe tutorial ([Step 5](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5))

Answer (score 0):

Try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) and [`cx-freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). These are the two most common ones you'll find out there. Most others are generally a derivative of cx-freeze